# Annotate with raw sql in Django1.3

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need to have the output of a method in the `list_filter` in the admin of a Django1.3 installation (where the class `SimpleListFilter` is not yet present).

I could build such a filter if I could annotate the variable `is_active` while fetching the queryset. As raw sql this would look like this:

```
SELECT *, active AND (end > NOW() OR end IS NULL) AND start < NOW() as is_active FROM app_model;
```

However, if I return this with the `queryset` method of the admin class, this will raise errors.

Is there a way to get my raw sql annotation into a proper django queryset?